# Use ASyncTask onProgressUpdate to update UI

Tags: android

I have an ASyncTask that tries to

1. find an image on disk
2. checks if newer online

Then in **onPostExecute** update the image

I would like to update image (i.e. sync to ui thread) both after checking disk (which is fast, but still to slow to do in e.g. ListView **getView**) and after checking online.

If I read the help correctly, I can call **onProgressUpdate** (executed in UI thread) by using **publishProgress(Progress...)** ... However, can I be sure of the order? I don't care about timing (if I have to wait a little) but I would like to make sure "disk-progress-state" happens before "online-progress-state"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you are asking if executing **publishProgress** invokes **onProgressUpdate** in the same sequence. The answer is yes, because it is posting messages via handler to the UI thread.

Here is the code from AsyncTask publishProgress

```
sHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_POST_PROGRESS, new AsyncTaskResult<Progress>(this, values)).sendToTarget();
```

Answer (score 2):

It's entirely up to you to decide when you call `publishProgress()` and what parameters you pass to it.

If you want to call it twice from your background thread - once after the disk check, and once after network check - then that's fine. To distinguish between the two calls in your `onProgressUpdate()` just keep track of what state you're in or keep a count of how many times that function has already been called.

The calls on the UI thread will be in the same order as the calls you make to `publishProgress()` in the background thread.

Answer (score 1):

`AsyncTask` runs the methods on the UI Thread by sending `Runnable`s to the main thread `Handler`. This `Handler` takes every `Runnable` in the FIFO queue and run them after another sequentially with no parallelism. Thus if the disk-progress-state happens before online-progress-state, then the order of the `publishProgress`'s is preserved.
The same applies to the order of publishProgress and onPostExecute.